# QLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'davidso_newmagento.tag' doesn't exist

Tags: magento

In my magento site , i click on a product:

Then i got this error:

`

There has been an error processing your request

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'davidso_newmagento.tag' doesn't exist

Trace:

> 0
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo-_execute(Array)  1
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300):
>   Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql-_execute(Array)  2
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479):
>   Zend_Db_Statement-execute(Array)  3
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract-query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)  4
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract-query('SELECT`main_ta...', Array)  5
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734):
>   Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql-query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)  6
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract-fetchAll('SELECT`main_ta...', Array)  7
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521):
>   Varien_Data_Collection_Db-_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)  8
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(566):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract-getData()  9
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Model/Resource/Tag/Collection.php(83):
>   Varien_Data_Collection_Db-load(false, false)  10
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Block/Product/List.php(68):
>   Mage_Tag_Model_Resource_Tag_Collection-load()  11
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Block/Product/List.php(45):
>   Mage_Tag_Block_Product_List-_getCollection()  12
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/design/frontend/base/davidsonbros/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(58):
>   Mage_Tag_Block_Product_List-getTags()  13
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241):
>   include('/hsphere/local/...')  14
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template-fetchView('frontend/base/d...')  15
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template-renderView()  16
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template-_toHtml()  17
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract-toHtml()  18
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Text_List-_toHtml()  19
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract-toHtml()  20
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract-_getChildHtml('content', true)  21
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(48):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract-getChildHtml('content')  22
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241):
>   include('/hsphere/local/...')  23
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template-fetchView('frontend/base/d...')  24
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template-renderView()  25
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Template-_toHtml()  26
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555):
>   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract-toHtml()  27
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout-getOutput()  28
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action-renderLayout()  29
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52):
>   Mage_Cms_Helper_Page-_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 
>   'no-route')  30
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75):
>   Mage_Cms_Helper_Page-renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 
>   'no-route')  31
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419):
>   Mage_Cms_IndexController-noRouteAction()  32
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action-dispatch('noRoute')  33
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard-match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>   34
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front-dispatch()  35
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/app/Mage.php(687): 
>   Mage_Core_Model_App-run(Array)  36
>   /hsphere/local/home/davidson/test.davidsonbros.com/index.php(90):
>   Mage::run('', 'store')  37 {main}

The `davidso_newmagento` is my databse.

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question but does your `davidso_newmagento.tag` table exist?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the `tag` table was removed.

You can **try** to push Magento to re_execute the tag module setup script.
To do that look for '**tag_setup**' row in table '**core_resource**' and remove it.
Then log out and log in in admin panel.

**I'm not sure it will works** as you probably will get some errors because some table already exist.

In case you got some error to fix them you can try one of the 2 suggestion:

1. You can 'play' with the setup scripts ( app/code/core/Mage/Tag/sql/tag_setup/... ): try to uncomment the DROP TABLE statement in mysql4-install-0.7.0.php ( just removing '--' before DROP ... )
2. You can remove manually the tables that gives problem.

   ( if you want to preserve tag data, export then and import after ... )